# MongoDB возвращает два раза один документ, с учетом того что этот документ в коллекции всего один

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В коллекции всего один документ с id 988807. При выборке из базы в массиве элементов документ с этим id встречается два раза. Как такое может быть и как от этого избавиться? При этом в таком же запросе, но с другими параметрами для запроса, дубликатов нет.

P.S: Не знаю, поможет ли эта информация, но дубликат приходит последним элементом массива

Пример запроса в bd:

```
Media.find(
        {
            param1,
            param2,
            param3: { $all: param3},
            param4: { $nin: param4},
        },
        {
            nameRu: 1,
            year: 1,
            actors: { $slice: 3 },
            genres: { $slice: 3 },
            ageRating: 1,
            kinopoiskId: 1,
            _id: 0,
        }
)
        .sort({ param5: -1 })
        .skip((pageNumber - 1) * limitNumber)
        .limit(limitNumber)
        .then(data => {
            Media.countDocuments(
                    {
                        param1,
                        param2,
                        param3: { $all: param3},
                        param4: { $nin: param4},
                    },
                    (err: any, count: number) => {
                        if (!err) {
                           console.log(data, count)
                        }
                    }
            )
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что нужно в сортировку обязательно добавлять сортировку по _id, поскольку если сортируете по полю, значение которого может быть одинаковым для нескольких записей, порядок записей может быть неопределенным и поэтому одна и та же запись может быть на разных страницах.